# Bootstrap Modal breaks with FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, fullcalendar

**Error I recieve:**

`0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'modal'`

The minute I apply the links for the fullcalendar, modals break.
Any reason for this?
I also did verify modals only broke when the javascript/stylesheets were added [I tested the calendar without and modal ran]

```
<link href='fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

If I define my calendar links before all my bootstrap it breaks the calendar saying it isn't supported as well.

So something with bootstrap and the fullcalendar either fights or overwrites each other.

My other local files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<script src="CSS/font-awesome-free-5.0.6/on-server/js/fontawesome-all.js"></script>  
<link href="CSS/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="CSS/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="CSS/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="CSS/maxcdn.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="Scripts/ajax.jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="Scripts/JavaScript.js"></script>
        <link href="CSS/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="Scripts/Splitter.js"></script>

        <link href="CSS/Oxygen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="CSS/passionOne.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="CSS/netdna_3.2.0_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="CSS/4.2.0_font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Wow, what a mess. You have included the bootstrap CSS at least 4 times there as I can count, and the theme CSS twice, as well as the font-awesome CSS twice, and randomly stuck a few JS scripts in there as well, I wouldn't be surprised if you've got some of them more than once as well based on that. You do appear to have the bootstrap JS, so make sure that's not added twice, and that it's included before you try to use it. Also I don't know what ajax.jquery.min.js but if it's really just a copy of jQuery, then you have got jQuery included twice, which is certainly a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think i remember having this issue a long time ago. I actually went into my conflicting file and looked for similar words. I think I would try naming everything in full calendar that is named modal, to modaltwo. Just a find and replace on the entire file. See if that works for you.

Comment: I see nothing with the term 'modal' in full calendar stuff. If I use the button `data-target` logic the modal runs; however, the javascript call breaks [which is what I use instead of data-target] `function openmodalcreateProd() {
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
     }`

Comment: so `lib\jquery.min.js` had 2 modal calls which i changed. still no luck

Comment: I commented out all `lib\...` files and modals worked.... sooooo... fullcalendar can't have those files called if you want bootstrap modals to run without using a button `data-target` modal launch

Answer (score 0):

So a warning to people like me who like to call `modal.show()` from vb.net code... the required `lib` jquery file can't be referenced with `fullcalendar`.

The bootstrap jquery files are all you need.

At this very moment I can't determine why the lib jquery file caused this bootstrap modal javascript break.

so I did the following links for fullcalendar [plus all my bootstrap files]:

```
<link href='fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script> <!-- need to calendar title -->
<%--<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>--%>
<script src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

so that I could use a javascript function call to show a modal like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function openmodal() {
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
 }

</script>
```

Comment: Your explanation is pretty garbled but what you really mean is you had jQuery added twice into the page, I guess?

Comment: @ADyson so I fixed my words. pretty much the fullCalendar required the lib jquery file; however, it was fighting my bootstrap jquery file. So by removing it, the bug was gone.

Comment: yeah you can't have two copies of jQuery in the page at the same time, they conflict. It doesn't matter which one you remove, as long as you load jQuery before both bootstrap and fullCalendar, and the one that remains is a high-enough version as required by both of those others.